# git clone on macOS only works on some Gitlab instances

Tags: git, macos, ssh, gitlab

currently I'm facing an issue with the `git clone` function on my MacBook. I've created a public and a private key by using the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` and saved both of them in the /.ssh directory in my local user under the name id_rsa. Then I've copied the public key by using `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and added it to my gitlab.com account. To tryout the connection I've used `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` and it directly works. Then I've changed the gitlab instance, since this was only a test and I've wanted to use the Gitlab of my company, where a colleague of mine already cloned our repo. I've pasted the exact same public key from the clip board into the Gitlab account on my companies gitlab und tried again to test the connection by using `ssh -T git@gitlab.devops.mycompanyname.de` and I've only received a timeout. My colleague directly sitting next to me (both with an external MacBook in the same public wifi, so basically same conditions) tried the same command and it worked for him. Then I've tried to clone the repo by using `git clone (https link to the repo)` and only received the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.devops.mycompany.de/pathtotherepo.git/': could not load PEM client certificate, LibreSSL error error:02FFF002:system library:func(4095):No such file or directory, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)

Then I've tried to start finding the cause and while trying a workaround I needed to install Homebrew from https://brew.sh/index_de. There I've just copied the install command `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"` and it started installing. Suddenly I received this (from my initial problem known) error message:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': could not load PEM client certificate, LibreSSL error error:02FFF002:system library:func(4095):No such file or directory, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
> Failed during: git fetch origin --force

Do you guys know anything that I'm missing or doing wrong? My colleague did the exact same thing with success and I'm not able to find a solution on the internet, since it already worked for gitlab.com. The responsible for my companies gitlab said that this issue shouldn't be caused by the gitlab installation, since hundreds of externals already cloned their repos there.

My last suggestion would be that it relates to my macOS installation, since I'm using Big Sur in the Build (20A4299v), but I couldn't find an issue like that in the apple dev community.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `git config -l` as a code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, whenever you are trying a git operation with HTTPS URL, that means your SSH key is not used at all.

> no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?

Nothing to do with SSH key, since you are using an HTTPS URL.

> ```
> could not load PEM client certificate, LibreSSL error error... No such file or directory,
> ```

Check your [`git config -l` as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52466468/6309) in order to check if you have an `http.sslCert` or `http.sslKey` specified to a file which does not exist.

Comment: Thanks that helped, found an old key in the git config that was configured for the same domain name. I've deleted it from the git config and then cloned the repo with an access token that I've added to my osX keychain.